# Unable to locate package libfam0-dev

Tags: 14.04, apt, package-management, source-packages, unsupported-packages

I am trying to install Maya 2015 on my laptop, Ubuntu 14.04, 64 bit, and I can't continue with `sudo apt-get install -y alien csh tcsh libaudiofile-dev libglw1-mesa elfutils gamin libglw1-mesa-dev mesa-utils xfs xfstt ttf-liberation xfonts-100dpi xfonts-75dpi ttf-mscorefonts-installer libfam0 libfam0-dev` because the package `libfam0-dev` is missing.

I get this error message:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package libfam0-dev
```

Comment: Simple : The right package name is `libfam-dev` ... for all Ubuntu versions ... http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=default&section=all&arch=any&keywords=libfam-dev&searchon=names ... Please always do a package search : `apt-cache search libfam`

Answer (score 0):

I believe the package you are looking for is `libfam-dev` and not `libfam0-dev`

You can install `libfam-dev` by typing the following in your terminal:

`sudo apt-get install libfam-dev`